# How to compile a C project in Netbeans using -lm -pthread arguments?

Tags: c, shell, unix, netbeans

I'm having a problem with compiling a C program in Netbeans. I can complile it with no problem in Shell using this command line: `gcc test.c -o test -lm -pthread`. Is it possible to configure Netbeans to compile the project with the `-lm` and `-pthread` arguments?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project (in the project tree) and choose "Project properties".

Then navigate to "Compiling" under "Build" and then there should be a field "Additional Compiler Options".